# Getting day of week when binding Date object to GridView Label (DateStringFormat)

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the Day of week out of a Date object that im binding to a gridview label like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="ResourceAvailabilityDayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

{0:d} shows only the day in numbers if the date was 11-4-2012 it will post 11. Is there a way to have this done during binding?  I cant find the correct DateStringFormat.

Edit

{0:dddd}  fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get day of the week use `ddd` or `dddd` [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
<asp:Label ID="ResourceAvailabilityDayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:dddd}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: {0:ddd} gives day in a short format, whilst  {0:dddd} gives full day names.